# sloped text along slanted paths in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Sloped text nodes along paths in a slanted scope seem off. Is there any way to fix this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\yslant}{0.5}
\newcommand{\xslant}{-0.6}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \begin{scope}[every node/.append style={yslant=\yslant,xslant=\xslant}, yslant=\yslant,xslant=\xslant]
        \draw (-0.5,5) -- (-0.5,2) node [midway, below, sloped] {weaker control flow};
        \draw (-0.5,5) -- (2,5) node [midway, above, sloped] {well-formedness};
        \draw (-0.5,5) -- (-2,2.5) node [midway, above, sloped] {number of exits};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**: I don't just need the axes, here's the whole figure:

[image]

Comment: My advice is to use rotate instead of slanting.  From what I can tell, the effect of slanting is x'=x(y) + xslant*y and y'= y(x) + yslant*x, so the results depend on which slant is performed first.

Comment: Excuse the pun but y slant?

Comment: I have a complex figure similar to this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12689/visualize-connection-between-two-slanted-tikz-scopes Can I do this using rotation?

Comment: The advantage of slant in the mentioned example is that it turns a rectangle into a parallelogram.  You could just draw a parallelogram, in which case you wouldn't need either slant or rotate.

Comment: Then again, if you want 3d text, you need xslant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is this sort of where you are headed?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfsetxvec{\pgfpoint{.866cm}{.5cm}}
\pgfsetyvec{\pgfpoint{.866cm}{-.5cm}}
\pgfsetzvec{\pgfpoint{0cm}{-1cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (5,0,0) node[midway,sloped,above,xslant=-0.5] {well-formedness};
\draw [->] (0,0,0) -- (0,5,0) node[midway,sloped,above,xslant=0.5] {weaker control flow};
\draw [<-] (0,0,5) -- (0,0,0) node[midway,sloped,above] {number of exits};
\path (2,1,0) node[rectangle,draw=black,rotate=30,xslant=-0.5] {test};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: new trial]

Comment: I don't just need the axes, the code I posted was just an MWE. I've updated my question.

Comment: I have better luck with xslant than yslant

Answer (score 2):

With PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\psset{nrot=:U,shortput=nab}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(6,6)
    \pcline{->}(2,2)(2,6)^{$y$-axis}
    \pcline{<-}(0,0)(2,2)^{$z$-axis}
    \pcline{->}(2,2)(6,2)^{$x$-axis}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You really like `pstricks` :D Tell me, are the direction of the axis manually set? I see numbers in your code. :P

Comment: @Alenanno: Yes. It was manually set up because I was not using the 3D package.

Comment: sorry, i'm really looking for a TikZ solution