# Why does sloped does not slope to the correct angle?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In this example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

 

\begin{document}

               \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=5,yscale=3]      

                              \tikzset{aufgabe/.style={fill=yellow}}        

                              \tikzset{pfeile/.style={->}}

                              \node [aufgabe] (i1) at (3,10) {Item1};     

                              \node [aufgabe,nearly opaque] (i2) at (4,9) {Item2};         

                              \draw [pfeile] (i1)--(i2)  node[sloped,midway,above]{Text};            

               \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Why does Text not get tilted to the correct angle?

[image]

Comment: Because you changed the ratio: `xscale=5,yscale=3`. Use the same and it will be OK.

Comment: Here is [a related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141274), and [another one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184225).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an answer but I hope it helps.

`\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5cm,y=3cm]`