# How can I bend a picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to "bend" a part of a tikzpicture, so that say the y axis is positioned at 45 degree.

I wonder if I can use the scope environment, someting like

```
\begin{scope}[yscale={(1,1)}] bla bla bla \end{scope}
```

(by the way, the above does not work.)

Comment: Do you want to simply rotate it?

Comment: not just rotate, I woul like to have the picture in a "diagonal" shape, with the x axis horizontal and the y axis at 45 degree. As a Pisa tower...

Comment: Are you looking for `yslant` as for example in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12689/visualize-connection-between-two-slanted-tikz-scopes ?

Comment: yes, (so "slant" is the right word!)

Comment: maybe I should remove the question?

Comment: Instead of deleting, you could write a short answer to help future users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The right word is SLANT.

In the answer to that question [[Visualize connection between two slanted TikZ scopes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12689/visualize-connection-between-two-slanted-tikz-scopes) ] a good example of how to use it.

I succesfully used

```
\begin{scope}[yslant=.5] bla bla bla \end{scope}
```

applied to a single node

```
\node[style={yslant=.5}] at (0,0) {bla ba bla};
```

or with scope, applied to all nodes

```
\begin{scope}[yslant=.5, every node/.append style={yslant=.5}] 
bla bla bla \end{scope}
```